# Alternative to gDistance and how to compute travel distance instead euclidean

Tags: r, distance, spatial, euclidean-distance

I have two questions,

first one; I have two different points data frame in a network, let's say position of stores and position of crimes. I want to compute distance matrix and want to see which crime is closer to which store or vice-versa.  I have wrote a code and used `gDistance()` works fine however, when there is 200K points vs 3K points it takes a bit time. I was wondering any alternative to `gDistance`.

Second question, gDistance uses euclidean distance can be seen in sample code as well. What if I want to use travel distance or taxi cap distance, anyone has an opinion how to compute this?

I have used `spatstat` package to create random points and convert them to `spatialpointsdataframe`. But it is for illustration.

```
library(spatstat)

set.seed(123)
randomSp=function(n1){
  Ra1=runiflpp(n1, as.linnet(chicago)) 
  Ra1df=as.data.frame(Ra1)
  Ra1df$xco=coords(Ra1)[,1]
  Ra1df$yco=coords(Ra1)[,2]
  Ra1df2=dplyr::select(Ra1df,x,y,xco,yco)
  coordinates(Ra1df2) = c("x", "y")
  proj4string(Ra1df2)="+proj=utm +zone=17 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
  return(Ra1df2)
}

B=Sys.time()

p1=randomSp(25000)
p2=randomSp(200)
p2@data$id=c(1:dim(p2)[1])

Xroad12=gDistance(p1, p2, byid = TRUE)  ## for each point should be belong to a road, using shordest-distance we will figure it out 
XRid=XRnume=NULL
for(i in 1:dim(p1)[1]){
  XRid[i]=Xroad12[which.min(Xroad12[,i]),i]
  XRnume[i]=which.min(Xroad12[,i])
}  ## computing shortest distance to closest intersection
p1@data$Swid=XRnume



plot(as.linnet(chicago))
plot(p2,col="red",add=T)
plot(p2[p2$id==3,],add=T,col="blue")
plot(p1,add=T)
points(p1[p1$Swid==3,],col="green")



E=Sys.time()

E-B
```

Comment: I've found nothing faster than `geosphere` for distance calculations, though I do see a significant difference in calc times between, say, `distHaversine` and `distVincentyEllipsoid`. I'm not surprised by this, just that it's noticeable. Other than that, I think your only way to get faster is to compile it yourself (not in R), sorry. *"taxi cab distance"*? There's a LOT more than goes into that, starting with having a network-graph of streets/intersections and metrics of "expected speed" to be able to **optimize** that route. (I haven't seen an R-centric way of doing that short of google-api.)

Comment: let me try if distHaversine is faster cause when I have 200K or more points it takes roughly an hour to run. Which is not if run once but it is long for repeating processes. 
Yes It depends on network to compute. Eventually I want to compute that. I just realized the typo "taxicab distance".  I am looking for suggestions where to start. So
distHaversine only works for lat/lon and I have x/y coordinates. I can convert but I prefer not to. Any other ideas?

Comment: Realize that with improved speed comes (technically) less accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was in front of my eyes, p1 and p2 are `spatialpointsdataframe` objects

```
p1ppp=as.ppp(p1)
p2ppp=as.ppp(p2)

XR12=nncross(p1ppp,p2ppp)
p1@data$Swid=XR12$which
p1@data$dist=XR12$dist
```

I have tried this for 200K for my regular data set. It normally takes an hour to run but it took couple minutes. I did few random example to make sure and it works.